# How to create Twitter widget?

Tags: javascript, widget, twitter

I want to create the Twitter widget for my web application.

I don't want to use the widgets provided by Twitter because if there are thousands of users then I have to create a separate widget for everyone, which is not possible.

I want to display all the tweets from the timeline of the user which is currently logged in to my web application.

I have to force my web application user to sign in to Twitter before accessing the timeline.

How to do that?

Is there anyone having detail idea about it?

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using this code,You can add your own twitter widget .You can also customize it.

```
  echo "<ul id='news'>";
  $twit_usr = 'username';//Please enter your twitter username
//$num_tweets = '60';
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open( 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/'.$twit_usr.'.xml/'                              );
while ( $reader->read() ) 
{
   if ( $reader->nodeType == XMLREADER::ELEMENT ) 
   {
      $name = $reader->name;
      if( $name == "status" )
      {
        while( $reader->read() )
        {
            if( $reader->nodeType == XMLREADER::ELEMENT )
            {
                $noName = $reader->name;
                if( $noName == "text" )
                {
                    $reader->read();
                    $checkUrl = $reader->value;
                    $text = preg_replace('/(?<!http:\/\/)(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]+)/i', '<a href="http://\1">\1</a>', $text);
                    $pattern = "#(http:\/\/[^ ]+)#i";
                    $replacement = "<a href=\"$0\" target=\"_blank\">$0</a>";
                    $finalString = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $checkUrl );
                    //$finalString = ereg_replace("[[:space:]]+[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]+[[:alnum:]]+[[:space:]]", "<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>", $checkUrl);
                    $result .= '<li>'.$finalString . '</li>';
                    //break;
                }//close if noName match

            }//close if nodeType
        }//close while reader read inner
      }//close if name item  
   }//close if nodeType
}//close while reader-read outer
 print_r($result);
 echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: thanks for reply,but I want it in javascript using OAuth for accessing public as well as private tweets of logged in user

Comment: Can you explain ,what you exactly want  ?

Comment: I want to display private and public tweets of user on my application.If you have seen the twitter widget for web application then I want exactly like that but its not possible to use that for thousands of user.And I want to display that tweets only if that user user is logged in to his twitter profile.